# SSL issues with Magento behind load balancer (302 loop)

Tags: ssl

In front of my Magento installation is a load balancer handling all the SSL stuff. If I don't tell Magento that it is receiving a secure connection it will go into a 302 redirect loop. The only [solution](http://naruzo.typepad.com/blog/2011/01/ssl-with-magento-behind-a-load-balancer.html) I found so far is to patch the main index.php like so (code goes right above the `Mage::run` line at the bottom the index.php):

```
/**
 * Prevent Magento from performing a 302 redirect loop.
 *
**/

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'])) {
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https') {
        $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
        $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = 443;
    }
}
```

(I added the content from the blog post with the addition from a commenter here, in case the link goes dead).

How can I avoid to patch a core file?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Thanks to a tip on the #magento-de irc channel I found a much more elegant solution. Add these lines to the end of your `.htaccess` and it should be fine:

```
# Detect the Load-Balancer-Header and set the header magento expects
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on
```

[Go here for a longer explanation.](http://www.aschroder.com/2012/07/magento-ssl-offloading-with-amazon-elb/)

Comment: DUDE. This solution fixed my problem!!! Thank you sooo much

Comment: Same here, this solved my issue.

Comment: worked for me too

Comment: After I used cloudflare to use free ssl, this solution helped fixing infinite loops issue.

Comment: This works for me. (Magento 1.9.3.0) Thanks

Comment: Fantastic! It works great for magento 1.9. For me it happened after cloudflare installation. But strange though, this redirect loop occur only after a few weeks of cloudflare implementation.

Comment: nginx solution https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/162392/https-not-working-on-magento2-backend/205248#205248