# HTTPS not working on Magento2 backend

Tags: magento2, ssl

I'm trying to enable our ssl certificate on *wijnmaat.nl* it is working for the frontend but the backend is giving us an error:

> ERR_TO_MANY_REDIRECTS

This is when I try to reach the backend trough https://www.wijnmaat.nl/admin. this is when ssl is enabled in the config in the backend & frontend and when it is off. Can somebody please help us with this?

We also checked and edited the secure base url to https://www.wijnmaat.nl

thanks,

Brent

Comment: .. found my solution. Will add an answer

Answer (score 4):

Based on the this [article](https://magenticians.com/magento-ssl-configuration-issues-resolved/) I was able to resolve it.

Check if the entry already exists.

```
select * from  core_config_data  where path = 'web/secure/use_in_adminhtml';
```

If not insert the following entry in the DB

```
INSERT INTO core_config_data (scope,scope_id,path,value) VALUES ('default',0,'web/secure/use_in_adminhtml',1);
```

else update the value and set it to 1

After inserting / updating the record [clean the cache via the CLI](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-flush-enable-disable-cache.html) : `php bin/magento cache:clean`

Answer (score 3):

I inserted the suggested SQL and I also had to add the following to nginx.

SQL

```
INSERT INTO core_config_data (scope,scope_id,path,value) VALUES ('default',0,'web/secure/use_in_adminhtml',1);
```

nginx

```
fastcgi_param  HTTPS "on";
fastcgi_param  HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO "https";
```

Which I got from here, https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9424

Answer (score 1):

Enable `HTTPS` for admin from Stores > Settings > Configuration > General > Web. Add this code below in your `.htacces` file:

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on
SetEnvIf HTTPS On HTTPS=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-FORWARDED-PROTO} !https 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.wijnmaat.nl/admin/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Clear all cache, deploy static content, enable 777 to pub and var directory.

Comment: Hi Pankaj, Thanks for helping out! Unfortunately. This didn't work 

But we enabled both HTTPS for frontend and backend and it worked. But we are not able to click on the menu on the left side. Nothing happens. Do you also know how to fix this? Thanks. Brent

Answer (score 0):

have you checked all settings properly?

Go then to Stores>Configuration from the admin panel
unfold the Base URLs (Secure) section 
Updating base URL http to https. 
Yes for Use Secure URLs on Storefront 
select Yes in using the Secure URLs on Storefront. 
now its done with HTTPS.

Source - https://www.sparxbpo.com/blog/enable-ssl-magento-2-store.html