# How to force https on magento 2?

Tags: magento2, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I'm using `Magento 2.3.1`, I have let's encrypt SSL installed, I want to force HTTPS in the admin area and the storefront end

in the admin panel, I go to

```
Stores > Configuration > General > Web
```

I put yet to "Use Secure URLs on Storefront" and yes to "Use Secure URLs in Admin"

That only enforces https in the admin area. I modifying `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

That doesn't work, I can't really play with apache that much, because I might break varnish which doesn't play well with HTTPS, tried that.

Is there an easy way to enforce HTTPS?

Comment: Guys silly question I made a mistake and enable without the certs ready, I want to disable and use http back I tried [bin]$ /www/server/php/82/bin/php magento setup:store-config:set --base-url="http://myip:892/admin_m1wky7/" --use-secure=0 --use-secure-admin=0 [bin]$ /www/server/php/82/bin/php magento cache:flush but it doesnt work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

to force HTTPS, change your base url to `https://` for unsecure too:

```
bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url="https://myshop.com/" --base-url-secure="https://myshop.com/" --use-secure=1 --use-secure-admin=1
bin/magento cache:flush
```

also if you have some redirect issues, you can add this to apache or .htaccess config:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: the .htaccess solution was spot on, even better than my answer which was hit and miss. your answer is the recommended one.

Answer (score 2):

Go to

`stores > configuration > general > web`

Put yet to "**Use Secure URLs on Storefront**" and **yes** to "**Use Secure URLs in Admin**", as you did before

Also put yet to "**Enable HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS)**"

Answer (score 0):

It seems an issue with the Magento application rather than the Helm chart itself.
I have found an answer that may solve your issue:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/38251

> Add these lines to the end of your `.htaccess` and it should be fine:
>
> ```
> # Detect the Load-Balancer-Header and set the header magento expects 
> SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on
> ```

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url="https://domain.com/" --base-url-secure="https://domain.com/" --use-secure=1 --use-secure-admin=1
bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: Isn't this basically just the answer from 2019?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I've solved the problem by running these 2 commands:

`sudo bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url="https://YOUR-DOMAIN-HERE/" --base-url-secure="https://YOUR-DOMAIN-HERE/" --use-secure=1 --use-secure-admin=1`

`sudo bin/magento c:f`

Note: replace the placeholder `YOUR-DOMAIN-HERE` by your custom domain name.