# Magento2 behind AWS load balancer too many redirect admin

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, https

I have install magento2 in AWS ec2 behind a load balancer . But when i try to access to login admin page i have error too many redirection

The problem is all solution i have fine not work .

I try all of this

```
php bin/magento config:set web/secure/use_in_adminhtml 1
php bin/magento config:set web/secure/use_in_frontend 1
php bin/magento config:set web/cookie/cookie_httponly 0
```

i try to put `web/unsecure/base_url` with a https

```
web/unsecure/base_url = https://example.com
```

i try too remove and add my domain name in this variable

```
web/cookie/cookie_domain NULL
web/cookie/cookie_domain https://example.com
```

i try to put this in my .htaccess

```
SetEnv X-Forwarded-Proto=https
SetEnv HTTPS=on
```

or

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on
```

i try too add on the index.php

```
$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

but i don't have `mage::run`

my index.php finish with this

```
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication(\Magento\Framework\App\Http::class);
$bootstrap->run($app);
```

my core_config_data look like this

```
0,web/cookie/cookie_httponly,0
0,web/secure/base_link_url,https://example.com
0,web/secure/base_url,https://example.com
0,web/secure/use_in_adminhtml,1
0,web/secure/use_in_frontend,1
0,web/seo/use_rewrites,1
0,web/unsecure/base_url,http://example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Before using setEnv for SSL variables, you must first initialize them using [SLOptions StdEnvVars](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#ssloptions).

After that you can define the variables referring to ssl:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  SSLOptions StdEnvVars
  SetEnv X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
  SetEnv HTTPS "on"
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer that may solve your issue:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/38251

Add these lines to the end of your .htaccess and it should be fine:

## Detect the Load-Balancer-Header and set the header magento expects

SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on

Could you try it?